# Constraint type-list length with a type family function

Tags: haskell

EDIT: I think I need to simplify this question:

I am using `generic-sop` library. I need to have a constraint '`a` has one constructor with at least 2 fields'. My functions look like this:

```
myFunction :: (Code a ~ '[ f1 ': f2 ': rest ]) => a -> something
```

However, I'd like to have this constraint as a 'type family'; i.e. I'd like to use e.g.

```
class (Code a ~ '[ f1 ': f2 ': rest) => Has2Records a
instance (Code a ~ '[ f1 ': f2 ': rest) => Has2Records a
myFunction :: Has2Records a => a -> something
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work - the variables in the `class` should appear as parameters to the `Has2Records`.

This simplifies the code; also, if I could do something like this, I could use it in the type family:

```
type family HowMany a r :: Constraint
type instance HowMany a Need1 = (Has1Record a)
type instance HowMany a Need2 = (Has2Records a)

class MyGreatClass a need where
  doSomething :: HowMany a need => a -> Something
instance MyGreatClass a Need1 where
  doSomething = (fneed1 :: (Code a ~ '[ f1 ': rest ]) => a -> Something)
instance MyGreatClass a Need2
  doSomething = (fneed1 :: (Code a ~ '[ f1 ': f2 ': rest ]) => a -> Something)
```

Comment: Do you think you could post the code in `iCreateTable` too? That way, we will know if we have evaded  your error.

Comment: Since you have a class `TableCreate`, you can simply put these constraints in the class instances - `instance (Code a ~ '[x0, x1], DynamoScalar x0, DynamoScalar x1) => TableCreate WithRange a where ...`. In this case, you simply remove `MinimumRecordSize` altogether. The instance `MinimumRecordSize NoRange '[ hash ': rest ] = ()` simply doesn't do what you think it does - it does not *provide* this constraint, but rather *require* it.

Comment: I am doing that - in this case it is not so bad as I can kind of assume the structure will have more fields even if not strictly needed, however it fails in other situations, see edit.

Comment: Re edit 2: Perhaps define a class `class HasHashAndRange (a :: [[*]]) where mkSomething' :: ...` and then `instance HasHashAndRange '[ hash ': range ': rest ] where mkSomething' = ...`. Define `f` over codes rather than original types, and with `f :: (SListI tables, All HasHashAndRange tables) => ...`. But more information would help. As it is, the question is not very concrete.

Comment: I have simplified the question. I need the constraint in the `class` - having it only as one of the `instance` doesn't help.